Why the split between feed document and feed?
I'm studying the API and am wondering why the split and multi-step upload. Can you create multiple feeds per feed document or something?

No, one feed corresponds to one feed document and one feed document corresponds to one feed.
This means that you cannot create multiple feeds for a feed document.
In fact, in order to upload a feed you must:

create a feed document, using the createFeedDocument
provide to the createFeed the feedDocumentId obtained from the previous call

Basically the feedDocument is the content of the feed, while the feed itself is something that tells Amazon to start processing something. What exactly is contained inside the linked feedDocument.

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review

Yes @kkakkurt, you are right. I improved my answer, hope this is ok now.
